# Integration Testing Sessions with Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I'm simply trying to write some tests to make sure logging in and out works, including everything that goes with it. Here's what I'm doing so far:

**tests/integration/sessions-test.js**

```
import Ember from "ember";
import { test } from 'ember-qunit';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';
var App;

module('Integrations: Sessions', {
  setup: function() {
    App = startApp();
  },
  teardown: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.destroy);
  }
});

test('Unsuccessful Sign In', function() {
  expect(3);
  visit('/sign-in');
  andThen(function() {
    fillIn('input#email', 'test@user.com');
    fillIn('input#password', 'bad_password');
    click('input#submit');
    andThen(function() {
      equal(currentRouteName(), 'sign-in', 'Unsuccessfull sign in stays on the sign in page.');
      ok($('input#email, input#password').hasClass('error'), 'Inputs have a class of "error."');
      equal($('input#submit').prop('disabled'), false, 'Submit button is not disabled.');
    });
  });
});

test('Successful Sign In', function() {
  expect(2);
  visit('/sign-in');
  andThen(function() {
    fillIn('input#email', 'test@user.com');
    fillIn('input#password', 'password');
    click('input#submit');
    andThen(function() {
      equal(currentRouteName(), 'welcome', 'Successfull sign in redirects to welcome route.');
      ok(find('.message').length, "Page contains a list of messages.");
    });
  });
});
```

And, here's a trimmed down version of the sign in logic behind the scenes:

**app/controllers/sign-in.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application'],

  actions: {
    signIn: function() {
      var self = this;
      var data = this.getProperties('email', 'password');

      // Attempt to sign in and handle the response.
      var promise = Ember.$.post('/v3/sessions', data);
      promise.done(function(response) {
        Ember.run(function() {
          self.get('controllers.application').set('token', response.access_token);
          self.transitionToRoute('welcome');
        });
      });

      ...
    }
  }
});
```

The "Unsuccessful Sign In" test works just fine. The "Successful Sign In" starts to work, then quits halfway through. It signs in, then redirects correctly. On the welcome page, when it makes a call to get the messages, the node server is responding with `Error: Not enough or too many segments` and a 500 status. What in the world does that mean and how can I fix it, assuming I don't have any control over the API?

Also, the API is written primarily using Koa and Passport, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently, it was an authentication error, not that you'd ever be able to guess that by the error message.

In the sign in controller, there's a line where I was setting the token property of the application controller. The application controller had an observer to watch that property for changes, then setup the AJAX headers when it changed. Problem is, observes use Ember's run loop, which is disabled while testing.

To fix the issue, I set the AJAX headers there in the sign in controller, just before transitioning to the welcome route.